# "Number" divs with the Alphabet using jQuery .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this to number divs that have the class "number":

```
$("#parent .number").each(function(i){
    $(this).html((i+1) + ". ");
});
```

but how would I use something similar to instead "number" as a,b,c,d etc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `string.fromCharCode`:

```
$("#parent .number").each(function(i){
    $(this).html(String.fromCharCode(97 + i) + ". ");
});
```

Also, if you would like to use capitalized characters, then use 65 instead of 97.

Comment: Well done Kurt! +1 @theatomicdude you can see a [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/agKrz/) and my version at the bottom.

Answer (score 6):

You can create an array of alphabet characters:

```
var alpha = ["a","b","c",....];
```

then use the index to print them:

```
$("#parent .number").each(function(i){
    $(this).html(alpha[i] + ". ");
    });
```

Just so you know, you can use an ordered list to do this using html and css:

The html:

```
<ol class="alpha">
   <li>text ...</li>
   <li>text ...</li>
   <li>text ...</li>
   <li>text ...</li>
</ol>
```

the css:

```
ol.alpha li {
   list-style-type:lower-alpha;
}
```

Comment: +1 For the CSS approach. This would be my preference. However, this questions implies they have no control over the content.

Answer (score 1):

```
var index = 97;
$("#parent .number").each(function(i){
    $(this).html(String.fromCharCode(index++));
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/agKrz/)

Comment: Looks great man, thanks for the demo too! Kurt answered first though, so I gave it to him, +1, Thanks!

Comment: @theatomicdude. I would have done the same thing... :) He deserves it (and need the rep more than I do)

Answer (score 1):

Does this *have* to be accomplished with Javascript? CSS counters could achieve the same effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/UZwqu/1/

```
#parent {
    counter-reset: my-counter;
}

#parent .number:before {
    content: counter(my-counter, lower-alpha);
    counter-increment: my-counter;
}​
```

More detail:

http://css-tricks.com/numbering-in-style/

Comment: Well the divs get reordered using javascript and i need to re"alphabatize" them on the fly.

Comment: This will automatically happen as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/UZwqu/3/

Comment: oh wow. Didn't know that! Thanks! I did ask for jQuery in my question, so I still have to give the answer to Kurt, but Thanks a lot!

Comment: but this doesn't work with divs though, I need to number DIVs :/

Answer (score 0):

```
var i=97;
$("#parent .number").each(function(){
    $(this).html(String.fromCharCode(i++) + ". ");
  });
```